# Symfony2 error when shopping cart is empty

Tags: php, symfony, session

In my project I can add products to the shopping cart and I can remove them. Everything works fine, however the problem is that when my cart is empty I am getting an error instead of just displaying the template without the cart. THe error is: **Variable "product" does not exist in...**. How can I bypass this error to show the template?

This is my shopping cart action:

```
public function summaryAction()
    {

            $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
            $cart = $session->get('cart', array());
            // fetch the information using query and ids in the cart
            if( $cart != '' ) {

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                foreach( $cart as $id => $quantity ) {
                          $productIds[] = $id;

                } 
            if( isset( $productIds ) )
                {
                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                    $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findById( $productIds );
                } else {
                    return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_summary.html.twig', array(
                        'empty' => true,
                    ));
                }

               return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_summary.html.twig',     array(
            'product' => $product,
                    ));
                } else {
                    return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_summary.html.twig',     array(
                        'empty' => true,
                    ));
                }
            }
```

This is my template:

```
{% if product %}  /// error at this line
              <tbody>

            {% for key, item in cart %}

              {% for item in product %}
                <tr>

                  <td> <img width="60" src="{{ asset('bundles/mpFrontend/assets/products/4.jpg') }}" alt=""/></td>

                  <td>{{ item.model }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="input-append"><input class="span1" style="max-width:34px" placeholder="1" id="appendedInputButtons" size="16" type="text">
                    <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-minus"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><a href="{{ path('cart_remove', {'id': key}) }}"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td>$120.00</td>
                  <td>$25.00</td>
                  <td>$15.00</td>
                  <td>$110.00</td>
                </tr>

                {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to check for variable/object presence:

```
{% if product is defined %}
```

This will check if you've assigned the variable product from your controller to your template.

```
{% if product is not empty %}
```

This will check if your product has any data in it or it's simply `null`. Beware that you must pass variable from the controller.

You can also combine them like this:

```
{% if product is defined and product is not empty %}
{# Show something when product is available #}
```